# Create DB call in the constructor via Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am learning MVC and I have some trouble with an online course I am taking and hoping that you can help me out.

I am shown the following example:

```
    public ActionResult Search()
    {
        var context = new DBFeedbackContext();
        ViewBag.CMC = context.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x, Value = x.Id.ToString() }).ToList();

        return View();
    }
```

And told in the course "this is not how you would do this in a real appliaction, you would call the Database in the controllers constructor via dependency injection, but for this simple example this is enough".
He then leaves this subject and never returns to it.

I would like to know what he's talking about and how you would do that, can you guys help?

Comment: [ASP.NET MVC 4 Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection)

Comment: Read about the concepts of inversion of control and dependency injection. It's a subject too broad to answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is completely correct way of doing things. Only problem I see in here is what context is not Disposed. You should write it like this instead:

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
    using(var context = new DBFeedbackContext())
    {
        ViewBag.CMC = context.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x, Value = x.Id.ToString() }).ToList();

        return View();
    }
}
```

Dependency Injection is not a "golden hammer" for everything. I think what he tried to say is you should create Database connection per controller/session, and this way you indeed better to do something like this:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    private readonly DBFeedbackContext _context;
    public MyController(DBFeedbackContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public ActionResult Search()
    {
        ViewBag.CMC = _context.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x, Value = x.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
        return View();
    }

    private ActionResult View(){ ... }
}
```

This way you will be able to delegate creation and managment of context lifetime **outside** your controller, because it is completely out of scope of tasks your controller solving. You mostly don't even care about how it is created/disposed, you just need it, and that's all.

Although, there is no harm in most use-cases if you constantly create contexts, they just taken/returned in connection pool, nothing else.